# Why doesn't fstream support an em-dash in the file name?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005

I ported some code from C to C++ and have just found a problem with paths that contain em-dash, e.g. "C:\temp\test—1.dgn". A call to fstream::open() will fail, even though the path displays correctly in the Visual Studio 2005 debugger.

The weird thing is that the old code that used the C library fopen() function works fine. I thought I'd try my luck with the wfstream class instead, and then found that converting my C string using mbstowcs() loses the em-dash altogether, meaning it also fails.

I suppose this is a locale issue, but why isn't em-dash supported in the default locale? And why can't fstream handle an em-dash? I would have thought any byte character supported by the Windows filesystem would be supported by the file stream classes.

Given these limitations, what is the correct way to handle opening a file stream that may contain valid Windows file names that doesn't just fall over on certain characters?

Comment: First you need to clarify what bytes your filename really contains. Passing an emdash (0x2014) to fopen will technically work with some casting or splitting it into two byte or whatever, but it won't be an emdash afterwards. Use eg. FindFirstFileW/FindNextFileW etc. and then look at the raw byte values.

Comment: Sorry, should have clarified that I just have a plain old C style single-byte string, not UTF8. The em-dash is represented as a single byte - 0x97, which should be a standard ANSI 8-bit character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this solution for others who run into this. The problem is that Windows assigns the "C" locale on startup by default, and em-dash (0x97) is defined in the "Windows-1252" codepage but is unmapped in the normal ASCII table used by the "C" locale. So the simple solution is to call:

```
setlocale ( LC_ALL, "" );
```

Prior to fstream::open. This sets the current codepage to the OS-defined codepage. In my program, the file I wanted to open with fstream was defined by the user, so it was in the system-defined codepage (Windows-1252).

So while fiddling with unicode and wide chars may be a solution to avoid unmapped characters, it wasn't the root of the problem. The actual problem was that the input string's codepage ("Windows-1252") didn't match the active codepage ("C") used by default in Windows programs.

Answer (score 1):

Character em-dash is coded as `U+2014` in UTF-16 (`0x14 0x20` in little endian), `0xE2 0x80 0x94` in UTF-8, and with other codes or not code at all depending on the charset and code page used. Windows-1252 code page (very common in western European languages) has dash character `0x97` that we could consider equivalent.

Windows internally manages UTF-16 paths, so every time a function is called with its bad-called ANSI interface (functions ending with `A`) the path is converted using the current code page configured for the user to UTF-16.

On the other hand, RTL of C and C++ could be implemented accessing to the "ANSI" or "Unicode" (functions ending in `W`) interface. In the first case, the code page used to represent the string must be the same of the code page used for the system. In the second case, either we directly use utf-16 strings from the beginning, or the functions used to convert to utf-16 must be configured to use the same code page of the source string for the mapping.

Yes, it is a complex problem. And there are several wrong (or with problems) proposal to solve it:

- **Use `wfstream` instead `fstream`:** `wfstream` do nothing  with paths different to `fstream`. Nothing. It just means "manage the stream of bytes like `wchar_t`". (And it does that in a different way as one can expect, so making this class unuseless in the most of cases, but that is another history). To use the Unicode interface in Visual Studio implementation, it exists the overloaded constructor and `open()` function that accept `const wchar_t*`. Those function and constructor are overloaded for `fstream` and for `wfstream`. Use `fstream` with the right `open()`.
- **`mbstowcs()`:** The problem here is the locale (which contains the code page used in the string) to use. If you match the locale because the default locale matches the system one, cool. If not, you can try with `mbstowcs_l()`. But these functions are unsafe C functions, so you have to be careful with the buffer size. Anyway, this approach could makes sense only if the path to convert is got in runtime. If it is an static string known at compile time, better is to use it directly in your code.
- **`L"C:\\temp\\test—1.dgn"`:** The `L` prefix in the string doesn't means "converts this string to utf-16" (source code use to be in 8-bit characters), at least no in Visual Studio implementation. `L` prefix means "add a `0x00` byte after each character between the quotes". So `—`, equivalent to byte `0x97` in a narrow (ordinary) string, it become `0x97 0x00` when in a wide (prefixed with `L`) string, but not `0x14 0x20`. Instead it is better to use its universal character name: `L"C:\\temp\\test\\u20141.dgn"`

One popular approach is to use always in your code either utf-8 or utf-16 and make the conversions only when strictly necessary. When converting a string with a specific code page to utf-8 or utf-16, tries to first convert to one of them (utf-8 or utf-16) identifying first the right code page. To do that conversion, uses the functions depending on where they come from. If you get your string from a XML file, well, the used code page is usually explicated there (and use to be utf-8). If it comes from a Windows control, use Windows API function, like `MultiByteToWideChar`. (`CP_ACP` or `GetACP()` uses to work as by default code page).

Uses always `fstream` (not `wfstream`) and its wide interfaces (`open` and constructor), not its narrow ones. (You can use again `MultiByteToWideChar` to convert from utf-8 to utf-16).

There are several articles and post with advices for this approach. One of them that I recommend you: http://www.nubaria.com/en/blog/?p=289.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, provided that *everything* you do is in wide-char notation with wide-char functions.  That is, use wfstream, but instead of using mbstowcs, use wide-string literals prefixed with the `L` char:

```
const wchar_t* filename = L"C:\temp\test—1.dgn";
```

Also, make sure your source file is saved as UTF-8 in Visual Studio. Otherwise the em-dash could get locale issues with the em-dash.

Comment: `L` prefix just will add a `0x00`byte after each other one. If the em-dash character `—` is coded as `0x12 0x82` (little endian of `#8212`). `L"  —" ` is equivalent to the bytes `0x12 0x00 0x82 0x00 0x00 0x00`, not `0x12 0x82 0x00 0x00`.